# Get option value from selectbox and paste to href

Tags: php, jquery, html, paypal

I have selectbox:

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

And paypal href getting few values to identify service that I'm selling, looks like this:

```
<a href="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=BUSINESSNAME&lc=BM&item_name=<?php 
echo $ppnazwa; ?>&amount=<?php echo rwmb_meta('sd_ppcost'); ?>%2e00&currency_code=EUR&button_subtype=services&no_note=0&bn=PP%2dBuyNowBF%3abtn_buynow_LG%2egif%3aNonHostedGuest" class="more-link">Pay by PayPal</a>
```

I would like to add value from selectbox, next to $ppnazwa value in paypal link. How I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like

```
$('.paypalAnchor').attr('href', $('.paypalAnchor').attr('href').replace('&amount', '&amount' + $('select').val()))
```

and give a class `paypalAnchor' to the link tag